# how can i send a post request to php file and get respond with webRequest in firefox extnesion?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, webrequest, firefox-addon-webextensions

i tried to send request to server and given respond with ajax but it is not working and after search, i find `webRequest` api 
How to use it correctly that include something like this:

url: https://example.com/example.php 
method: post 
param: name=john

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use the webRequest Api for that.

Nevertheless you are going to run into another problem: Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)

If you want your extension to be able to make requests to `example.org` you will need to ask for permission on that host. The permission request is being made in your `manifest.json` as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#Host_permissions).

When you have granted your extension permission to the host, you can simply fetch data via ajax.